# aws DMS replicate-changes-only error

Tags: mysql, replication, data-migration, amazon-aurora, dms

I have prod aws Aurora DB and I want
to replicate changes to test mysql DB (schema is same - Aurora is based on mysql)
I am using aws DMS for this.

When performing full replication for certain tables the replication works fine,
When I want to perform replicate-changes-only, the replication fails.
I've set binlog_checksum=NONE and binlog_format=ROW in the parameter group.

The error I am receiving while running is:
Last Error The task stopped abnormally Stop Reason RECOVERABLE_ERROR Error Level RECOVERABLE
Last Error Task 'task-id' was suspended due to 6 successive unexpected failures Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL

Loading a snapshot to the test db isn't an option.
I just want to replicate the changes between specific tables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post how this issue was resolved please?

Comment: Check this: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=223281

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same error, it was always stopping 10min after starting. Adding more verbose logs didn't show more information but by changing the task configuration, especially the parameter `MaxFullLoadSubTasks`.

By default the value is `"MaxFullLoadSubTasks": 8,`, I changed it to `"MaxFullLoadSubTasks": 1,`.
It is slower but it's working for now. You may be able to increase it a bit to be quicker without having the same error.

You can modify the task configuration by first copying the task json settings you will find under DMS > TASK > overview, then changing the value and saving it to a file and then:

`aws dms modify-replication-task --replication-task-arn <TASK_ARN_ID> --replication-task-settings file:///path/to/your/task_config.json`

Comment: Were you also running `replicate-changes-only` ? The setting `MaxFullLoadSubTasks` does not apply to that mode.

Comment: I can't remember, it was in full mode I think